# Como passar variável entre funções de classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-kivy, kivy

Preciso passar a variável `price` para a função `whatever` de `Tela4`. Sou novato tanto em programar quanto na linguagem em si e tô com sérios problemas nessa solução apesar de imaginar que seja bem simples.

O código atualmente está assim (`cost_output` faz referência a uma *label* de Kivy):

```
class Tela2(Screen):
    def op_dimoff(self):
        self.price = float((int(self.ngd) * 0.87 * 1.75) + self.price_inv)

class Tela4 (Screen):
    def whatever(self):
        tela_two = Tela2
        self.cost_output.text = str(tela_two.price)
```

Comment: Está com algum problema? Seu código não parece estar completo.

Comment: @Maniero a primeira pergunta que faço aqui então pensei que poderia não ser uma boa ideia colocar o código inteiro pra não ficar algo tão grande. Em resumo, implementando assim acima eu recebo um erro  ```AttributeError: 'Tela2' object has no attribute 'price'```

Comment: Inteiro não é bom, mas partes relevantes é. Neste caso parece que nem tem o campo

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Variáveis são artifícios da linguagem e existem em código, então você não as passa, você passa os valores que as variáveis suportam. Neste caso parece que nem quer passar nada, quer apenas acessar o estado de uma variável existente em outra classe.

As variáveis precisam existir, então teria que ser algo assim:

```
class Tela2(Screen):
    price = 0.0
    def op_dimoff(self):
        self.price = float((int(self.ngd) * 0.87 * 1.75) + self.price_inv)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/PassVariable.py).

Note que a variável `price` aí pertence à classe e não do método (o que você chamou de função, mas que tem esse nome quando está dentro de uma classe), é importante fazer esta distinção, se ainda não entende isto precisa aprender antes de prosseguir.

Mas quero fazer algumas considerações:

- se isto for mais que eu exercício [não é correto usar este tipo de dado para valor monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).
- para conseguir programar é necessário entendimento do que está fazendo, ou seja, precisa construir o conhecimento para fazer coisas avançadas, e ao que parece está com dificuldade em algo básico em um problema avançado. Eu reveria a forma de aprender só indo para o avançado quando domina o básico, é bem mais produtivo.